# List View Threshold Error - Based on User

Tags: 2010, list-view-threshold

I have a SP list with over 29K items.  Because of the LVT, I have created views where the number of items returned are under 5K.  I have an indexed column, Tester (Name and Group), which the views filters on.  The filter is equal to [Me].

Today, a tester when to access their view and recieved the list view threshold error.  I went in, and reassigned all their items to my name, and I was able to see all the items - SP didn't give me the LVT error.

The total number of items returned is in the 3000-3500 range.  Any idea why it is given the error to some users but not to me?  I have Designer and Total access permissions but I don't see how this would affect the limit.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two thresholds. One for normal users, typically defaults are set at 5000. Another limit for Site Collection Administrators, typically defaults are set at 20,000